# Serverless error

Tags: kotlin, gradle, amazon-web-services

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь выполнить команду:

```
serverless create --template "aws-kotlin-jvm-gradle" --path my-service
```

но неизменно ловлю ошибку:

```
 Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

 Template "true" is not supported. Supported templates are:..
..... "aws-kotlin-jvm-gradle"....
```

Может ли кто-то подсказать, в чем здесь дело?

Спасибо!

Comment: А без кавычек после --template?

Comment: да, похоже так работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так надо ([см. тут](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/create/)):

```
serverless create --template aws-kotlin-jvm-gradle --path my-service
```

Comment: ты волшебник, я писал ровно это же раз 15..